# noob question about function ()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am not sure about this code. This structure is correct?

```
 success: function(data, data1, data3, .... ) {
                    switch (data.livre) {
                    case 'x':

                        break;
                    }

                    switch (data1.livre1) {
                    case 'y':

                        break;
                    }

                }
```

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For future reference here is a code quality tool : [jshint](http://www.jshint.com)

The above is indeed "correct" code as in it will parse correctly. But it can be improved though.

```
success: function(data) {
  if (data.livre === 'x') { 
    ... 
  }
  if (data.livre1 === 'y') { 
    ... 
  }

}
```

Be wary that you generally pass one result back. So you should get the server to pass an object or array of data back.

The real question is, do you have a problem? and what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: my doubt is about the number of parameters of function. is clear now, thanks

Comment: @user773961 the number of parameters is 1

Comment: But if you are using objects then you don't even really need them to be passed back in a lot of cases because JS always passes by reference.

Comment: @JonathonWisnoski I'm assuming it's the jQuery ajax success call so it needs objects passed in from the server

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure which part of the function you're asking about, but maybe you mean either:

```
function success( ... ) { .... }
```

Or,

```
success = function( ... ) { .... }
```

Using `success: function` doesn't make sense in isolation, but people are so used to reading that as a JS object property they might think its ok...

Answer (score 0):

If that's inside of an object, sure.  Looks right to me.

i.e.

```
var obj = {
     success: function(...
};
```